# Load and Reload data in service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have an angular service as follows:

```
export class AuthService {

  private data$: Observable<DataModel[]>;

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService, private dataService: DataService) { }

  getData() {

    this.data$ = this.dataService.get();

  }

  authorize(requirement: Requirement) : Observable<boolean> {

    // Code that uses $data. Example:

    return this.data$.pipe(
      map(data => data.type == 12))
    );

  }

}
```

And `DataService` is simply the following:

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public get(): Observable<DataModel[]>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<DataModel[]>>(`auth/data`);
  }  

}
```

I inject `AuthService` in components and directives which call the authorize method.

The method `authorize` needs `data$` to be set by using `getData()`.

And `data$` must also be reloaded, using `getData()`, when a notification is detected:

```
this.noteService.get().subscribe((note: Note) => { 

  if (note.code == 0) 
    this.getData(); // Reload data

});
```

**Questions**

I am not sure how to integrate this requirements in the AuthService.

1. How to check if `data$` is defined and get the initial data?
2. Where to check if a notification with code 0 is received and reload `data$`?
3. How to be sure the code inside `authorize` method waits for data$ to finish being loaded in case is being loaded when authorize is called?
   Either because is initially being loaded or because is being reloaded?

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of your `DataService` to help me better understand the source of your observable?

Comment: I just update my answer. `DataService` gets data from an API using `HttpClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if data$ is defined and get the initial data?

```js
if (!this.data$) {
 this.getData()
}
```

---

> Where to check if a notification with code 0 is received and reload data$?

You could check this condition inside `noteService` and use a subject to let any of `noteService`'s consumers that a notification has been received:

#### note.service.ts

```js
private notificationReceivedSubject = new Subject();
public notificationReceived$ = this.notificationReceivedSubject.asObservable();

this.noteService.get().subscribe((note: Note) => { 

  if (note.code == 0) {
    this.notificationReceivedSubject.next(true);
  }

});
```

#### auth.service.ts

```js
constructor (private noteService: NoteService, /* ... */) {
 this.noteService.notificationReceived$
  .subscribe(() => this.getData()); // Reload data when notification is received
}
```

---

> How to be sure the code inside authorize method waits for data$ to finish being loaded in case is being loaded when authorize is called?

This might require you to change a bit the way you're currently doing things.
Looks like another entity is depending on the state(`data$`) from `authService`. 
In such cases, I'd use a `BehaviorSubject` in order to keep track of the last emitted value.

There are a few changes to be made before:

#### auth.service.ts

```js
private dataStore = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public data$ = this.dataStore.asObservable();

get data () {
 return this.dataStore.value; // Get the current value
}

getData () {
 this.dataStore.next(null); // `data` currently not available

 this.dataService.get()
  .subscribe(data => this.dataStore.next(data));
}
```

The answer to this question would be this:

```js
this.authService.authorize(r)
 .pipe(
  tap(v => !v ? this.showLoader() : this.hideLoader()),
  filter(v => !!v) // Get data only when it is ready
 ).subscribe(d => console.log('data ready!', d))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would leave out the subscription. You can do something like this:

```
export class AuthService {

  private data$: Observable<DataModel[]>;
  private note$: Observable<NoteModel[]>;

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.note$ = this.noteService.get();

    this.data$ = this.note$.pipe(
      filter(note => note && note.code == 0),
      switchMap(note => this.dataService.get()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something but where are you getting the initial data to fill `data$`? I mean, when `authService` is first injected is should call `dataService.get(`). And then call it again every time the `noteService` emits a note with code 0